# Visual Basic 6 and UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, vb6

currently I have a ancient VB6 procedure that open text file as follow

```
Public Function ApriFile(sFile As String, iCanale As Integer) As Boolean
  On Error GoTo ApriFileErr
  ApriFile = False
  NumberError = 0
  sErrore = ""

  Close #iCanale

  'Apertura archivio di input
  Open sFile For Input As #iCanale

  ApriFile = True
  Exit Function

ApriFileErr:
  ApriFile = False
  'Errore nell'apertura del file
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    NumberError = Err.Number
    sErrore = Err.Description
  End If

End Function
```

How can use the UTF8 charset?

I need to open the file, read line by line using the UTF-8 charset and then write on another file always with the same charset.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15809081/1070452

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450156/write-text-file-in-appending-utf-8-encoded-in-vb6

Comment: your problem is not clear .. can you please give more details

Comment: I've added to the existing answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809081/encoding-of-text-files-in-vb-6-0 to answer your question. As a result, I've voted to close this question.

Comment: I've added to the existing answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809081/encoding-of-text-files-in-vb-6-0 to answer your question. As a result, I've voted to close this question.